# Otimização no código PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

olá, estou estudando uma forma de incrementar um valor antes de guardar no banco de dados mas preciso de ajuda, buscando no Google por partes consegui montar o código e sim funciona, objetivo dele é atualizar um valor no banco de dados, mas eu estou achando o código confuso alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<?php

try{
$id = 1;

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=isbn_db", "root", "");

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//busca no banco de dados
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM isbn ORDER BY numero_isbn"); 
$stmt2->execute();

//fecAll busca todos os resultados
$results = $stmt2->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//BUSCA O VALOR NO BANCO DE DADOS 
foreach ($results as $value){
    $var = $value['numero_isbn'];   
}    

//incrementa o valor obtido no banco
$var = $var + 10000000000;   

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE isbn SET numero_isbn = :numero_isbn WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':id' => $id,
    ':numero_isbn' => $var
));

// echo $stmt->rowCount();

echo "ISBN: ".$var;

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
    echo "ERRO";
}

?>
```

Comment: A primeira coisa que tem que perguntar, por que usa PDO? Qual sua justificativa para adotá-lo?

Comment: eu tambem maniero.  eu gostaria de saber porque PDO, e tambem a razao pela qual ele quer incrementar esse numero no php. Gustavo? A incrementação automatica do MYSQL não resolve? um numero RANDOMICO, resolve seu problema ?

Comment: Isso poderia ser feito em uma única query, algo como `UPDATE isbn SET numero_isbn = :numero_isbn + 10000000000 WHERE id = :id`

Comment: Realmente não avia um motivo para usar PDO, e não o incremento automático do MYSQL não me ajuda, na verdade para este caso eu precisava gerar este numero sequencial, então apos um pouco mais de estudo reformulei meu código, posso postar o código? para talvez futuramente ajude alguém?

Comment: Está piorando. Você acha que consegue fazer um controle de sequência melhor que o MySQL consegue? Acho que você precisa reavaliar isso.

Comment: Só um `numero_isbn = numero_isbn + 10000000000` no update substituiria todo o seu código, mas não afirmo que essa seja a solução, pois mal entendi o que está querendo fazer, incluindo o fato de talvez um valor ISBN ser numérico.

Comment: piorando? apenas estou pedindo ajuda com código pois comecei a pouco estudar sobre isso, não to julgando se é melhor ou pior que o MySQL, mas para o pouco conhecimento que eu tenho no momento eu preferi incrementar este valor tratando ele dentro do meu código, sei que no futuro vou olhar o meu código e sentir vergonha mas no momento é o que eu consigo fazer, pois comecei a aprender isso ontem, podem encerrar esta minha pergunta, Anderson fiz o que você sugeriu e o código diminuiu bastante, com sua ajuda consegui dar uma enxugada nele, fiquem com Deus aquele abraço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muitos programadores (inclusive eu há alguns anos atrás) faria o seguinte procedimento para somar um valor a uma coluna no banco:

- Um Select para obter a quantidade atual
- A adição do valor
- Por último um Update para atualizar coluna

> Existe uma forma mais rápida e correta de se fazer este procedimento.

```
    SET numero_isbn = numero_isbn + :numero_isbn
```

### Otimização do código PHP PDO

```
$id = 1;
$var=10000000000;

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=isbn_db", "root", "");

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE isbn SET numero_isbn = numero_isbn + :numero_isbn WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':id' => $id,
    ':numero_isbn' => $var
));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda assim posso diminuir meu código, aquele abraço